What is the right way to send a serialized struct over boost.interprocess.?
I am trying to send a struct of data over shared memory, using boost interprocess. I want to serialize the data and send it as binary.
I am basing my approach on this answer:
Send complex data structure via boost message queue
However once I have switched to my struct type, my code does not send the data. Everything compiles and runs fine. However when I close and re-open the receiver application, the data no longer sends / receives. How can I do this in such a way that the receiver can be closed and opened, and will automatically pick up the connection again?

File datastruct.hpp
 #ifndef DATASTRUCT_HPP
 #define DATASTRUCT_HPP

 #include <string>
 #include <vector>

 #include <boost/serialization/vector.hpp>

 #define MAX_SIZE 150000

 namespace dataStruct {

     struct VUserPoint {
         float PositionX;
         float PositionY;
         float PositionZ;

         template <typename Archive> void serialize(Archive& ar, unsigned int const version) {

             ar & PositionX;
             ar & PositionY;
             ar & PositionZ;
         }
     };

     struct FvpData {

         // Array of current points in frame
         std::vector<VUserPoint> UserPoints;
         int                     frameNumber;

         template <typename Archive> void serialize(Archive& ar, unsigned int const version) {
             ar & UserPoints;
             ar & frameNumber;
         }
     };

 } // namespace dataStruct

 #endif // DATASTRUCT_HPP


File sender.cpp
 #include "DataSender.h"
 #include <boost/archive/binary_iarchive.hpp>
 #include <boost/archive/binary_oarchive.hpp>
 #include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
 #include <boost/interprocess/ipc/message_queue.hpp>

 using namespace boost::interprocess;

 int num = 1;

 void DataSender::Grab(std::vector<Eigen::Vector3d> points) {
     dataStruct::FvpData data;
     // add userpoints
     data.UserPoints.clear();
     for (int i = 0; i < points.size(); i++) {
         dataStruct::VUserPoint pnt;

         pnt.PositionX = points[i].x();
         pnt.PositionY = points[i].y();
         pnt.PositionZ = points[i].z();

         data.UserPoints.push_back(pnt);
     }
     num             += 1;
     data.frameNumber = num;

     try {
         message_queue mq(open_or_create, "mq", 100, MAX_SIZE);

         std::stringstream oss;

         boost::archive::binary_oarchive oa(oss);
         oa << data;

         std::string serialized_string(oss.str());
         mq.send(serialized_string.data(), serialized_string.size(), 1);

         std::cout << data.frameNumber << std::endl;
     } catch (interprocess_exception& ex) {
         std::cerr << ex.what() << std::endl;
     }
 }


File receiver.cpp
 #include <iostream>
 #include <string>

 #include <boost/archive/binary_iarchive.hpp>
 #include <boost/archive/binary_oarchive.hpp>
 #include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
 #include <boost/interprocess/ipc/message_queue.hpp>

 #include "DataStruct.hpp"

 using namespace boost::interprocess;

 int main() {

     try {
         message_queue mq(open_or_create, "mq", 100, MAX_SIZE);

         message_queue::size_type recvd_size;
         unsigned int             priority;

         while (true) {
             dataStruct::FvpData me;

             std::stringstream iss;
             std::string       serialized_string;
             serialized_string.resize(MAX_SIZE);
             mq.receive(&serialized_string[0], MAX_SIZE, recvd_size, priority);
             iss << serialized_string;

             boost::archive::binary_iarchive ia(iss);
             ia >> me;

             std::cout << me.frameNumber << std::endl;
             //   std::cout << me.name << std::endl;
         }
     } catch (interprocess_exception& ex) {
         std::cerr << ex.what() << std::endl;
     }

     //  message_queue::remove("mq");
 }




Firstly, extract a [mcve] and include that along with how you run it in the Q. Also include the actual output you get and what you would expect instead. That said, you seem to have a mix of tabs and spaces, which makes your code a nuisance to read, please run the code you paste here through an autoformatter for readability. BTW: Consider submitting your code to codereview.stackexchange.com, too, see their different guidelines first, though.

Firstly I simplified and extended the reproducer:

File datastruct.hpp
 #pragma once
 #include <boost/serialization/vector.hpp>
 static constexpr inline size_t MAX_SIZE = 150'000;
 namespace dataStruct {
     struct VUserPoint {
         float PositionX, PositionY, PositionZ;
         void serialize(auto& ar, unsigned) { ar & PositionX & PositionY & PositionZ; }
     };

     struct FvpData {
         std::vector<VUserPoint> UserPoints;
         int                     frameNumber;
         void serialize(auto& ar, unsigned) { ar & UserPoints & frameNumber; }
     };
 } // namespace dataStruct


File sender.cpp
 #include "datastruct.hpp"
 #include <Eigen/Core>
 #include <boost/archive/binary_iarchive.hpp>
 #include <boost/archive/binary_oarchive.hpp>
 #include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
 #include <boost/interprocess/ipc/message_queue.hpp>
 #include <iostream>

 namespace bip = boost::interprocess;

 static int num = 1;

 void Grab(std::vector<Eigen::Vector3d> points) {
     dataStruct::FvpData data{{}, ++num};
     for (auto const& p : points)
         data.UserPoints.push_back(dataStruct::VUserPoint{
             .PositionX = static_cast<float>(p.x()),
             .PositionY = static_cast<float>(p.y()),
             .PositionZ = static_cast<float>(p.z()),
         });

     try {
         bip::message_queue mq(bip::open_or_create, "mq", 100, MAX_SIZE);

         std::stringstream oss;

         {
             boost::archive::binary_oarchive oa(oss);
             oa << data;
         } // completes the archive!

         std::string serialized_string(oss.str());
         mq.send(serialized_string.data(), serialized_string.size(), 1);

         std::cout << data.frameNumber << std::endl;
     } catch (bip::interprocess_exception const& ex) {
         std::cerr << ex.what() << std::endl;
     }
 }

 #include <random>
 #include <thread>
 int main() {
     std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(3);

     std::mt19937 gen(std::random_device{}());
     std::uniform_real_distribution<double> dist(-10, 10);

     for (int n = 100; n--; std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1))) {
         std::vector<Eigen::Vector3d> points;
         for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
             auto x = dist(gen), y = dist(gen), z = dist(gen);
             points.emplace_back(x, y, z);
             std::cout << x << " " << y << " " << z << std::endl;
         }

         Grab(points);
     }
 }


File receiver.cpp
 #include "datastruct.hpp"
 #include <boost/archive/binary_iarchive.hpp>
 #include <boost/archive/binary_oarchive.hpp>
 #include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
 #include <boost/interprocess/ipc/message_queue.hpp>
 #include <iomanip>
 #include <iostream>
 #include <sstream>
 #include <string>

 namespace bip = boost::interprocess;

 int main() {
     std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(3);

     try {
         bip::message_queue mq(bip::open_or_create, "mq", 100, MAX_SIZE);

         bip::message_queue::size_type recvd_size;
         unsigned int                  priority;

         while (true) {
             dataStruct::FvpData me;

             std::stringstream iss;
             std::string       serialized_string;
             serialized_string.resize(MAX_SIZE);
             mq.receive(&serialized_string[0], MAX_SIZE, recvd_size, priority);
             iss << serialized_string;

             boost::archive::binary_iarchive ia(iss);
             ia >> me;

             std::cout << me.frameNumber << std::endl;
             for (auto const& p : me.UserPoints)
                 std::cout << p.PositionX << " " << p.PositionY << " " << p.PositionZ << "\n";

         }
     } catch (bip::interprocess_exception const& ex) {
         std::cerr << ex.what() << std::endl;
     }

     //  message_queue::remove("mq");
 }



Next up, I verified that normal operation is okay.
The Problem: Safe Stop
You don't say how you stop the program(s). Since there's nothing in the code shown, I might assume that you use Ctrl-C (or worse):

As you can see you get a lock exception. You need to cleanly exit. You can implement your own graceful shutdown, or use signals to intercept Ctrl-C/termination:
std::atomic_bool shutdown{false};

boost::asio::thread_pool io{1};
boost::asio::signal_set  sigs(io, SIGINT, SIGTERM);
sigs.async_wait([&](boost::system::error_code const& ec, int num) {
    std::cerr << "Signal " << ::strsignal(num) << " (" << ec.message() << ")" << std::endl;
    shutdown = true;
});

e.g. Adjusted sender.cpp
#include "datastruct.hpp"
#include <Eigen/Core>
#include <boost/archive/binary_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/binary_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/ipc/message_queue.hpp>
#include <iostream>

namespace bip = boost::interprocess;

static int num = 1;

void Grab(std::vector<Eigen::Vector3d> points) {
    dataStruct::FvpData data{{}, ++num};
    for (auto const& p : points)
        data.UserPoints.push_back(dataStruct::VUserPoint{
            .PositionX = static_cast<float>(p.x()),
            .PositionY = static_cast<float>(p.y()),
            .PositionZ = static_cast<float>(p.z()),
        });

    try {
        bip::message_queue mq(bip::open_or_create, "mq", 100, MAX_SIZE);

        std::stringstream oss;

        {
            boost::archive::binary_oarchive oa(oss);
            oa << data;
        } // completes the archive!

        std::string serialized_string(oss.str());
        mq.send(serialized_string.data(), serialized_string.size(), 1);

        std::cout << data.frameNumber << std::endl;
    } catch (bip::interprocess_exception const& ex) {
        std::cerr << ex.what() << std::endl;
    }
}

#include <random>
#include <thread>
int main() {
    std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(3);

    std::mt19937                           gen(std::random_device{}());
    std::uniform_real_distribution<double> dist(-10, 10);

    std::atomic_bool shutdown{false};

    boost::asio::thread_pool io{1};
    boost::asio::signal_set  sigs(io, SIGINT, SIGTERM);
    sigs.async_wait([&](boost::system::error_code const& ec, int num) {
        std::cerr << "Signal " << ::strsignal(num) << " (" << ec.message() << ")" << std::endl;
        shutdown = true;
    });

    try {
        for (; !shutdown; std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1))) {
            std::vector<Eigen::Vector3d> points;
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
                auto x = dist(gen), y = dist(gen), z = dist(gen);
                points.emplace_back(x, y, z);
                std::cout << x << " " << y << " " << z << std::endl;
            }

            Grab(points);
        }
    } catch (std::exception const& ex) {
        std::cerr << ex.what() << std::endl;
    }

    io.join();
}

See it live:

Observations
You serialize doubles as floats. That loses precision.
You copy everything multiple times: first from Eigen to your data struct, then to a string stream, from the stream to a string then to the queue, etc.
I'd suggest using serialization directly on the Eigen data. It seems to me it could be zero-copy:
static_assert(std::is_standard_layout_v<Eigen::Vector3d>);
static_assert(sizeof(Eigen::Vector3d) == 3 * sizeof(double));

Sadly, Eigen's implementation is somehow not trivially-copyable (I think this may be incidental?). However you can see a lot of answers on the net (and on this site) showing how to serialize Eigen vectors and matrices directly.
BONUS
Here's a version that

avoids the double->float conversion

avoids unnecessary copies

avoids unnecessary archive overhead:
 static auto constexpr ar_flags =               
     boost::archive::archive_flags::no_header | 
     boost::archive::archive_flags::no_codecvt |
     boost::archive::archive_flags::no_tracking;


avoid deadlocking on full/empty queue by using timed_send and timed_receive


Live On Compiler Explorer
#include <boost/archive/binary_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/binary_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/ipc/message_queue.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/device/array.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/stream.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/is_bitwise_serializable.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/vector.hpp>

#include <Eigen/Core>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <thread>
static constexpr inline size_t MAX_SIZE = 150'000;

// tentative despite the types not being trivially-copyable
// static_assert(std::is_trivially_copyable_v<Eigen::Vector3f>);
static_assert(std::is_standard_layout_v<Eigen::Vector3f>);
static_assert(sizeof(Eigen::Vector3f) == 3 * sizeof(float));
BOOST_IS_BITWISE_SERIALIZABLE(Eigen::Vector3f);

// static_assert(std::is_trivially_copyable_v<Eigen::Vector3d>);
static_assert(std::is_standard_layout_v<Eigen::Vector3d>);
static_assert(sizeof(Eigen::Vector3d) == 3 * sizeof(double));
BOOST_IS_BITWISE_SERIALIZABLE(Eigen::Vector3d);

static auto constexpr ar_flags =                //
    boost::archive::archive_flags::no_header |  //
    boost::archive::archive_flags::no_codecvt | //
    boost::archive::archive_flags::no_tracking;

static std::atomic_bool g_shutdown{false};
using namespace std::chrono_literals;
namespace bip = boost::interprocess;
namespace bio = boost::iostreams;

static auto constexpr QUEUE_NAME = "7be6183b-de45-4c06-9fae-f1fbdcd24b66";
bip::message_queue g_mq(bip::open_or_create, QUEUE_NAME, 10, MAX_SIZE);

static auto now() { return std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now(); }
static constexpr auto timeres = 500ms;

void receiver() {
    for (std::string buf; !g_shutdown;) {
        buf.resize(MAX_SIZE);
        bip::message_queue::size_type recvd_size;
        unsigned int                  priority;

        for (auto t = now() + timeres; !g_shutdown; t += timeres) {
            if (g_mq.timed_receive(&buf[0], MAX_SIZE, recvd_size, priority, t))
                break;
        }
        buf.resize(recvd_size);

        bio::stream<bio::array_source>  arrstr(buf.data(), buf.size());
        boost::archive::binary_iarchive ia(arrstr, ar_flags);

        int                          frameNum;
        std::vector<Eigen::Vector3f> points;

        ia >> frameNum >> points;

        std::cout << frameNum << std::endl;
        for (auto const& p : points)
            std::cout << p.x() << " " << p.y() << " " << p.z() << "\n";
    }
}

void sender() {
    std::mt19937                           gen(std::random_device{}());
    std::uniform_real_distribution<double> dist(-10, 10);
    std::array<char, MAX_SIZE>             buf;

    for (int frameNum = 1; !g_shutdown; std::this_thread::sleep_for(timeres)) {
        std::vector<Eigen::Vector3f> points;
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
            auto x = dist(gen), y = dist(gen), z = dist(gen);
            points.emplace_back(x, y, z);
            std::cout << x << " " << y << " " << z << std::endl;
        }

        frameNum += 1;
        bio::stream<bio::array_sink> arrstr(buf.data(), buf.size());
        boost::archive::binary_oarchive(arrstr, ar_flags) << frameNum << points;

        for (auto t = now() + timeres; !g_shutdown; t += timeres) {
            if (g_mq.timed_send(buf.data(), arrstr.tellp(), 0, t)) {
                std::cout << "Sent " << arrstr.tellp() << " bytes, frameNum " << frameNum << std::endl;
                break;
            } else {
                std::this_thread::sleep_until(t);
                std::cout << "Waiting..." << std::endl;
            }
        }
    }
}

void on_signal(boost::system::error_code ec, int signum) {
    std::cerr << "Signal " << ::strsignal(signum) << " (" << ec.message() << ")" << std::endl;
    g_shutdown = true;
}

int main(int argc, char**) try {
    std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(3);
    boost::asio::signal_set sigs(boost::asio::system_executor{}, SIGINT, SIGTERM);
    sigs.async_wait(on_signal);

    if (argc > 1) {
        receiver();
    } else {
        sender();
        // bip::message_queue::remove(QUEUE_NAME);
    }
} catch (std::exception const& ex) {
    std::cerr << "Error: " << ex.what() << std::endl;
}

With a proper stress-test:


Added a bonus version integrating many more improvements and also removing edge-cases by using timed_send and timed_receive
